# How do you write a function in pygame that draws one or more objects?

Tags: python, pygame

I am a relative newbie in both python and pygame. I am trying to learn with a visual calculator project. In it, I draw a rectangle which works fine:

```
pygame.draw.rect(screen, COLOR3, Rect = pygame.Rect(65, 450, 400, 100))
```

but if I do the following:

```
def draw_rect():
   pygame.draw.rect(screen, COLOR3, Rect = pygame.Rect(65, 450, 400, 100))
```

and I try to invoke it with `draw_rect`, I get nothing.
I've tried adding some parameters in the `()` of the function but i couldn't get that to work.

Comment: Your code above is fine and the problem is probably elsewhere in your code. Make sure `screen` has been defined at the point where you call `draw_rect`

Answer (score 1):

To draw one or more, you just update positions, then loop through all your objects in a draw routine.  Hard to say where yer having trouble without seeing more of what you've written.  It's possible rectangles *are* displaying, but they're outside of the screen area, so you don't see them.  Best thing to do is [look at examples](https://www.pygame.org/docs/tut/ChimpLineByLine.html) 'til you get a better idea of the desired syntax.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

import pygame
from random import uniform

##~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

pygame .init()

origin = 0, 0
size = width, height = 400, 300
screen = pygame .display .set_mode( size )
pygame .display .set_caption( 'Jitter' )

white = 255, 255, 255
red = 255, 0, 0
green = 0, 255, 0
blue = 0, 0, 255
black = 0, 0, 0

background = pygame .Surface( screen .get_size() )
background = background .convert()
background .fill( white )

red_pos, red_size = ( 50, 50 ),  ( 50, 50 )  ##  left, top,  width, height
green_pos, green_size = ( 190, 130 ),  ( 20, 20 )
blue_pos, blue_size = ( 300, 50 ),  ( 50, 50 )
black_pos, black_size = ( 50, 220 ),  ( 300, 20 )

red_rect = pygame .Rect( red_pos, red_size )
green_rect = pygame .Rect( green_pos, green_size )
blue_rect = pygame .Rect( blue_pos, blue_size )
black_rect = pygame .Rect( black_pos, black_size )

def update_positions():  ##  move "in-place", as opposed to creating a new object
    red_rect .move_ip( uniform(-2, 2),  0 )
    green_rect .move_ip( 0,  uniform(-2, 2) )
    blue_rect .move_ip( uniform(-2, 2),  0 )
    black_rect .move_ip( uniform(-2, 2),  0 )

def draw_stuff():
    pygame .draw .rect( screen,  red,  red_rect )
    pygame .draw .rect( screen,  green,  green_rect )
    pygame .draw .rect( screen,  blue,  blue_rect )
    pygame .draw .rect( screen,  black,  black_rect )

run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame .event .get():
        if event .type == pygame .QUIT:
            pygame .quit()
            run = False

    screen .blit( background, origin )
    update_positions()
    draw_stuff()
    pygame .display .flip()

##  eof  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Answer (score 0):

I know I have had this problem (or similar one) billions of times before and it is SO annoying! My guess is that you have forgotten `pygame.display.update()` at the end of your main loop or `draw_rect()`.
I hope this solves your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

`Rect =`  is not necessary, Remove it and try:

This is how you have to draw a rectangle:

```
pygame.draw.rect(screen, COLOR3, pygame.Rect(65, 450, 400, 100))
```

Use this code in the function like this(don't forget to call it):

```
def draw_rect(): 
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, COLOR3, pygame.Rect(65, 450, 400, 100))

draw_rect()
```

and call the method inside the loop like so:

```
run = True
while run:
    
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            run = False
            
    draw_rect()
    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a list. Create a list of colors and rectangles:

```py
rects = [
    (COLOR1, pygame.Rect(65, 150, 400, 100)),
    (COLOR2, pygame.Rect(65, 300, 400, 100)),
    (COLOR3, pygame.Rect(65, 450, 400, 100))]
```

Draw the objects in a loop:

```py
def draw_rects(rects):
   for color, rect in rects:
       pygame.draw.rect(screen, color, rect)
```

```py
draw_rects(rects)
```